# Inserting dynamic few shot examples with Llama Index SQLTableRetrieverQueryEngine

Tags: prompt, langchain, llama-index

I am trying to insert dymanic few shot examples per https://docs.llamaindex.ai/en/stable/examples/prompts/prompts_rag.html#adding-few-shot-examples

into my SQLTableRetrieverQueryEngine prompts.

I am using the following code try to create the template and pass examples to it.

````
RESPONSE_TEMPLATE_STR = """
If the <SQL Response> below contains data, then given an input question, synthesize a response from the query results.
If the <SQL Response> is empty, then you should not synthesize a response and instead respond that no data was found for the question.


Question: {query_str}
SQL: ```{sql_query}```
<SQL Response>: {context_str}</SQL Response>

Here are a few example answers:
\n{few_shot_examples}

Response:
"""

RESPONSE_PROMPT = PromptTemplate(
    RESPONSE_TEMPLATE_STR,
    function_mappings={"few_shot_examples": few_shot_examples_fn},
)


query_engine = SQLTableRetrieverQueryEngine(
        sql_database,
        obj_index.as_retriever(similarity_top_k=5),
        service_context=service_context,
        text_to_sql_prompt=SQL_PROMPT,
        response_synthesis_prompt=RESPONSE_PROMPT,
    )
````

However, I now get the error

```
ValueError: response_synthesis_prompt must have the following template variables: query_str, sql_query, context_str
```

So it appears response_synthesis_prompt does not allow any other template variables than those three. Is there any way around this? I tried using partial format but this still gave me the same error. Is there a way to "flatten" the template, so the few shot examples variable gets converted to a string before passing it as response_synthesis_prompt or text_to_sql_prompt?